# Не могу вставить текст в графу Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

Только начал изучать Selenium, не могу разобраться

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("https://web.telegram.org")
time.sleep(3)

xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div[2]/label'
phone = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).clear()
phone.send_keys(705122225)

time.sleep(3)
browser.quit()
```

Вроде все как в уроке делаю. Пишет invalid element state

Comment: в каком уроке и в какой строке пишет ошибку?

Comment: browser.get("http://web.telegram.org") здесь выдает DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62559/devtools/browser/cf60f6c0-8d42-4e8b-b64a-6a6557536334
[14132:16128:1216/185750.754:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [18:57:50.754] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1020 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: ╧Ёшёюхфшэхээюх ъ ёшёЄхьх єёЄЁющёЄтю эх ЁрсюЄрхЄ. (0x1F)
[14132:16128:1216/185751.805:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(211)] [18:57:51.806] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1073 Getting Default Adapter failed.

Comment: phone = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).clear() а здесь selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state

Comment: протокол urlа смените на  **https**://web.telegram.org/

Comment: Сменил. То же самое

Comment: Первую ошибку проглатывает, но я боюсь из-за нее возникает и вторая

Comment: вам нужно вставить номер в поле ввода? найдите селектор div по классу **login_phone_num_input_group** и в него вставьте?

Comment: или номер передайте строкой: phone.send_keys("705122225")

Comment: Это оказывается браузер постоянно разные xpath выдает. Как по css селектору их искать? Вот допустим селектор ```body > div.page_wrap > div > div.login_page > div.login_form_wrap > form > div.login_phone_groups_wrap.clearfix > div.md-input-group.login_phone_code_input_group.md-input-has-value.md-input-animated > input
``` Где его имя?